# Create a dataframe column based on values that are columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first one looks like:

| Age | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 32 | 50 |
| 2 | 42 | 73 | 20 |

The second dataframe looks like

| ID | Age | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 200 |
| 23 | 1 | 300 |

My goal is to create another column in the second dataframe which fetches the value from the first dataframe by the corresponding values of both the column Age and Score.
The Score's are the columns in the first dataframe.

The resulting dataframe:

| ID | Age | Score | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 200 | 42 |
| 23 | 1 | 300 | 32 |

Answer (score 2):

Try with `melt` and `merge`

```
tomerge = df1.melt('Age',var_name = 'Score',value_name='Count')

tomerge['Score'] = tomerge['Score'].astype(int)
out = df2.merge(tomerge)
out
Out[988]: 
   ID  Age  Score  Count
0  10    2    200     42
1  23    1    300     32
```

Comment: I miss `df.lookup`.

Comment: @ScottBoston me too , really do not know why they remove the function....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) from df2 and map it onto a series created with 'Age' index followed by a stack from df1.

```py
    df2.Count = pd.Series(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.Age, df2.Score]).map(df1.set_index('Age').stack())
    )
```

Intermediate outputs:

```py
    df1.set_index('Age').stack()
    Age     
    1    200    34
         300    32
         400    50
    2    200    42
         300    73
         400    20
    dtype: int64
    
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.Age, df2.Score])
    
    MultiIndex([(2, 200),
                (1, 300)],
               names=['Age', 'Score'])
```

print(df2):

```py
       ID  Age  Score  Count
    0  10    2    200     42
    1  23    1    300     32
```